# TypeError: method() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a method in a class enigmaRotor:

```
def apply_permutation(index, permutation, offset):
        new_index = index + offset
        if new_index > 25:
            new_index = new_index - 25
        permutated = permutation[new_index]
        final_index = ALPHABET.find(permutated)
        final_index -= offset
        if final_index < 0:
            final_index = 25 + final_index
        
        return final_index
```

and I try to call said method from another class with these two methods:

```
def key_pressed(self, letter):

        self.lamps[self.fastrotor.apply_permutation(ALPHABET.find(letter), self.fastrotor.get_permutation(), self.fastrotor.get_offset())] = True
        self.keys[letter] = True
        self.update()

def key_released(self, letter):

        self.lamps[self.fastrotor.apply_permutation(ALPHABET.find(letter), self.fastrotor.get_permutation(), self.fastrotor.get_offset())] = False
        self.keys[letter] = False
        self.update()
```

because I create 3 objects of the enigmaRotor class in the constructor of the primary class EnigmaModel:

```
class EnigmaModel:

    def __init__(self):
        """Creates a new EnigmaModel with no views."""
        self._views = [ ]

        self.slowrotor = enigmaRotor(ROTOR_PERMUTATIONS[0])
        self.mediumrotor = enigmaRotor(ROTOR_PERMUTATIONS[1])
        self.fastrotor = enigmaRotor(ROTOR_PERMUTATIONS[2])
```

but I get the following error on the "key pressed" and "key released" actions:
TypeError: enigmaRotor.apply_permutation() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.

Why might this be, or what could I be missing that is causing this?

As far as I can see, I am only providing three attributes into the apply_permutation method.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki Parameter, not argument.

Comment: Yep, `self`. The 4th positional argument it is referring to it the `self` it attempts to pass when you call the object from the binded instance, but the program isn't able to find the self slot.

You either want,

```
def apply_permutation(self, index, permutation, offset)
```

or make this method a static method.

Comment: Despite the name, `index` is assigned `self.fastrotor`, `permutation` is assigned `ALPHABET.find(letter)`, `offset` `self.fastrotor.get_permutation()`, which leaves no parameter left for self.fastrotor.get_offset().

Comment: My assignment claims that the apply_permutation "is easiest to implement as a top-level (not nested inside anything) function in the EnigmaRotor.py module". Could there be any other possible reason?

Comment: That's sort of what I was getting at with the static method idea. It doesn't need to be a method since it doesn't depend on an instance of a class. It sounds like you have it in a class at the moment, but it doesn't have to be. In that case you would just call `apply_permutation` instead of `self.fastrotor.apply_permutation`.